# Web Service Proxy call becomes slow only in the context of IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

So my C# web forms app calls an external 3rd party SOAP web service using an auto-generated SOAP client (ServiceReference). Initially, everything works as expected with the calls taking 1 to 2 seconds, no matter how many calls are made.

However after time goes by (in terms of hours) the calls be come slower and slower. So after the app has been running for 12 to 18 hours call take 20 to 30 seconds. After 24 hours the can take 60 seconds. Recycle the web app and we are back to 1 to 2 seconds per call.

First thing I did was open Fiddler to see when the request actually shows up. For the short calls the request shows up immediately. For the longer calls, the request shows up just before the end, for example during a 30 second call it won't show in Fiddler until 28 second after the proxy makes the call.

I tried eliminating possible problems by doing the following:

1. Built a console app using the same code that uses the proxy. It ran for just over two days and never slowed down making a call every 10 min.
2. Just before making the proxy call I make a call using a raw WebClient (hard coded xml body) to the same soap service. The WebClient never slows down.

   ```
             Service Proxy | Web Request
    IIS    | Becomes slow  | Stays fast
   Console | Stays fast    | Stays fast
   ```

Any thoughts?

What is happening between the time proxy makes the call and the call actually going out on the wire?

Whatever is happening in between, why would it become slower and slower?

Comment: Have you looked at the memory usage of `w3wp.exe` after 12-24 hours? You could have a memory leak.

Comment: @CamBruce - I have looked... nothing. Memory and CPU are both fine.

Comment: How is the service called on IIS. It is firing every 10 min, just like the console application? If so, how did you set this up?

Comment: @CamBruce - There is a button on the page that triggers the call. The button only get's clicked 100 or so times in 24 hours.

Comment: You can always try to configure the application pool in IIS that your app is running under to recycle faster than the default, which is 24 hours.